# invalid_grant invalid assertion POST /services/oauth2/token

Tags: oauth2, jwt, postman

I followed up [this guide](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/c360-postman/blob/main/install-the-collection.md) and I believe I did it correctly. However I'm receiving this error from POSTMAN

```
POST /services/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.28.4
Accept: */*
Postman-Token: f1d7ec10-e6a4-4f95-9f90-26fed50254e3
Host: login.salesforce.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 706
Cookie: BrowserId=zyWz9g9pEeyy0XtmUn91KA; CookieConsentPolicy=0:0
 
grant_type=urn%3Aietf%3Aparams%3Aoauth%3Agrant-type%3Ajwt-bearer&assertion=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiIzTVZHOWNISDJiZktBQ1piQTZBRVlxQ2pZanBwcGdMN3BRN0hxZVFUeFRCT2tRNFRjNnA0T05KUWtQanY4bnFBLnhhYmpmR0tOellJU1k2RUNjM3kwIiwic3ViIjoibWFyaW8uc2FsdmFkb3IucnVpemZvbnQrY2RwMUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJhdWQiOiJsb2dpbi5zYWxlc2ZvcmNlLmNvbSIsImV4cCI6MTYzMDk3MjM3Mn0.c1vl5pjDtLc52foPZFqhP3zMcWVQdcO9TdfRSLwxwpjeBU9YaeACLqEEW-FtQdcGrO3ZB0dDs6Ju_knK39cgCvR9UK2vzS9C8f5gf4di2rGn3SKMkgk5kcvthkAaRuV0EF9Cs16ww2glhJasBuLY9tRemDGUo0O9m86QEobu53DuPz0IFKFTOwQ4ViqrbGIIenP_skjRSNY1hZJYdKCoReBodbXNoTmAqqXvFWEFGiuIbJtshNZH94r_Iz1H_OdkMSh9i09sJmfRcDvA6fQQDk3BYPaOSRTGzc8eY-uRvaUSt2LEaygeureYyIYz4R_TtTII3tF8cCA5foYIsnlO_Q
 
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Mon, 06 Sep 2021 23:52:53 GMT
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache,must-revalidate,max-age=0,no-store,private
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
 
{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"invalid assertion"}
```

Not able to fix it yet...

Comment: What Salesforce product are you after and/or what are you trying to accomplish? The doc you reference is for integration with [Customer Data Platform (CDP)](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/customer-360-audiences-basics/meet-customer-360-for-marketers)

Comment: Yes, SF CDP. It's an integration with the REST API.

Comment: I re-followed the guide of config and I was able to fix this issue. My apologies.